# Why do we need all 3 - tesser, transducers core.reducers in Clojure

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing

I'm trying to get my head around all the different abstractions used for parallel computations in Clojure. When reading about the topics I get lost in all the details in lengthy articles.

I'm looking for a short answer

- why we need different libraries and
- when to use and when NOT to use a specific library.

So far the ones that confuse me because they look the same are

- [tesser](https://github.com/aphyr/tesser),
- transducers (with core.async pipeline),
- core.reducers (parallel folds)

Comment: I see transducers and reducers as being more applicable to parallel programming, and core.async to Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP) style concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

That's (still) a great question!

I only note that tesser uses reducers, folds (or, hugs!), and provides access to efficient and multicore processing. It has some constraints, in terms of requiring functions to be associative and commutative.  Both have foldr (fold right), which is, 'on the path to laziness'.

Transducers have foldl, too.  A left fold is, apparently, 'on the loop path'. It appears that, with transducers, you can take your pick!

The 2014 Vimeo video that I saw pointed out a shortcoming of transducers, where the programmer needs to obtain intermediate results. Clojure stateful transducers might address a lot of the issues, resolved in tesser.

I'm new to the subject so, I'm just working through it, myself!